# Facebook signed in user in rails how to access its information and get subscriptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, omniauth, facebook-access-token, koala

I'm usign omniauth to login user from facebook and I'm also using devise gem so in my devise.rb initializer file. I added

```
config.omniauth :facebook, app_id, app_secret,
    {:scope => 'email, offline_access', :client_options => 
      {:ssl =>
          {:ca_file => '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'}
      }
    }
```

and Its working perfectly as I have user 'signed in' in my app but the problem is I'm not getting how to move on and get user profile info and its friends info and also Subscription and status updates.

Therer are graph Api methods available

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(acess_token)
    @profile = @graph.get_object("me")
    @friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
```

But I'm not getting how to get **"acess_token"** to do all this stuff.

So summing up I need AccessToken kindly provide clear answer plzz

awaiting your response

Answer (score 0):

yahooo got it :)

in the follwing method **$access_token = auth.credentials.token** statement is pointed to get access token.

```
def self.find_for_provider_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
    user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
    $access_token = auth.credentials.token
    unless user

      user = User.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
        provider:auth.provider,
        uid:auth.uid,
        email:auth.info.email,
        password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      )
    end
    user
  end
```

OR you can get it,by this

```
request.env["omniauth.auth"].credentials.token
```

Is there any other best way to get access_token plzz share I need optimization and good practice but for now its working.